# SWIFT MT Message SEME Uniqueness

Tags: swift-mt

As far as I understand, the `SEME` (sender's message reference) attribute of a SWIFT MT message has to be unique per sender (it is the sender's responsibility to ensure uniqueness). So, let's say there are two sending entities A and B and I am the receiver. Then it would be a valid scenario to have both of them send out a SWIFT MT message with the same SEME, right? How could I differentiate messages coming from sender A and B? What is common practice in such a case?

In the [documentation](https://www.iso20022.org/15022/uhb/mt558-3-field-20c.htm) (MT 558 in that case) it says:

> Reference assigned by the triparty agent to unambiguously identify the
>   message.

Comment: You use a combination of SEME, TCTR and TRCI iirc.

Comment: Hi @BurhanKhalid, can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The MIR in the {2: Application Header Block} seems to be the one according to me.
MIR: message input reference, unique identifiers containing the date, logical terminal (including branch code), session and sequence numbers. 
Info source: https://www.prowidesoftware.com/about-SWIFT.jsp